# Parsing some Java code with Python using ANTLR

Tags: python, parsing, antlr, antlr4, python-3.8

I want to build a Java parser using ANTLR in Python.

I downloaded the grammars from the ANTLR repository:

Lexer :https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/java/JavaLexer.g4

Parser: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/java/JavaParser.g4

Then I used my script.bat to generate the python code I need :

```
java -jar antlr-4.8-complete.jar -Dlanguage=Python3 Java8Lexer.g4
java -jar antlr-4.8-complete.jar -Dlanguage=Python3 Java8Parser.g4
```

`antlr-4.8-complete.jar` downloaded here: https://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.8-complete.jar

This generated this list of files:

- Java8Lexer.interp
- Java8Lexer.py
- Java8Lexer.tokens
- Java8Parser.interp
- Java8Parser.py
- Java8Parser.tokens
- Java8ParserListener.py

Then I wrote this code to parse a java file:

```
import antlr4
from antlr4 import *
from java.antlr_unit2 import Java8Parser, Java8Lexer

def main():
    code = open('test.txt', 'r').read()
    lexer = Java8Lexer.Java8Lexer(antlr4.InputStream(code))
    stream = antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = Java8Parser.Java8Parser(stream)
    tree = parser.expression()
    print (tree)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My test java code `test.txt` is something like this:

```
package org.jabref.gui.fieldeditors;
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 * This class contains some code
 */
public class TextInputControlBehavior {

    private static final boolean SHOW_HANDLES = Properties.IS_TOUCH_SUPPORTED && !OS.OS_X;

}
```

Since this is too short, here is an example of code I want to parse: https://pastebin.com/KNxfasKQ

When I run this code I get this :

```
line 1:0 extraneous input 'package' expecting {'boolean', 'byte', 'char', 'double', 'float', 'int', 'long', 'new', 'short', 'super', 'this', 'void', IntegerLiteral, FloatingPointLiteral, BooleanLiteral, CharacterLiteral, StringLiteral, 'null', '(', '!', '~', '++', '--', '+', '-', Identifier, '@'}
[]
```

Am I doing something wrong? I didn't wrote the grammar, I just took it from ANTLR repo.

**EDIT**: **Pavel Smirnov**'s answer helped me and now I don't get the warning. But now the program seems really slow and i get an empty tree as output.

**SOLVED**: I was printing `tree` but I had to `print(tree.toStringTree(recog=parser))`

So the final code is:

```
import antlr4
from antlr4 import *
from java.antlr_unit2 import Java8Parser, Java8Lexer

def main():
    code = open('test.txt', 'r').read()
    lexer = Java8Lexer.Java8Lexer(antlr4.InputStream(code))
    stream = antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = Java8Parser.Java8Parser(stream)
    tree = parser.compilationUnit()
    print(tree.toStringTree(recog=parser))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text file contains a `compilationUnit`, not an `expression` you try to parse with

```
tree = parser.expression()
```

Look carefully through the parser rules, the rule you need is

```
compilationUnit
    : packageDeclaration? importDeclaration* typeDeclaration* EOF
    ;
```

which has to be called as

```
tree = parser.compilationUnit()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I don't get that warning now! But i don't get an output, the program is looped. I'm trying to understand why. I update the question by adding a better example for `test.txt`

Comment: I got an empty tree output