# Parsing out Abstract Syntax Tree of a VB code using antlr and python

Tags: antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

Mycode(in python):

```
lexer = VisualBasic6Lexer(antlr4.InputStream(code))
stream = antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer)
parser = VisualBasic6Parser(stream)
tree = parser.visitModule()  //This visitModule() is not the coreect method.
    print(tree)
```

I followed this link:
[Parsing some Java code with Python using ANTLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60617218/parsing-some-java-code-with-python-using-antlr)

Here,for Java they have used

```
tree = parser.compilationUnit()
```

In VB what is the alternative of this compilationUnit()

Grammar I used-
https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/vb6/VisualBasic6Lexer.g4
https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/vb6/VisualBasic6Parser.g4

My goal is to export the Abstract Syntax Tree of a VB code using python into a JSON File.

See the output in this link  https://github.com/Sdccoding/proleap-vb6-parser

I want my output to be in this beautified fashion.

Comment: The default print routine in the Antlr Python runtime does not pretty print with indentation. You're going to have to write an output routine of the tree, stack based or a recursive approach. See https://github.com/Sdccoding/proleap-vb6-parser/blob/master/src/test/java/io/proleap/vb6/util/TreeUtils.java for an example. If you write one, write a second method to just output json.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the root node you need to visit is at the start of the parser file.
Also, a characteristic for the root node is it ends with EOF.

For your case,

```py
tree = parser.startRule()
```

Comment: How to beautify the output I am getting?
I am geeting in this manner:
(startRule (module (moduleBody (moduleBodyElement (subStmt (visibility Private)

I want this:
(startRule
  (module
    (moduleBody
      (moduleBodyElement
        (subStmt

Comment: Seems your wanted tree is incomplete, btw, what's your input code?

Comment: Because long comments are not allowed,so I gave the incomplete output.What I mean to say is,I want to see beautified json(like trees),but what I am getting is not the beautified version...Its written (startRule (module (moduleBody (moduleBodyElement (subStmt (visibility Private)  like this.

Comment: import json, then `print json.dumps(tree, sort_keys=True, indent=4)`

Comment: No change..Its still the same only.I want my output to be as https://github
.com/Sdccoding/proleap-vb6-parser , this link's output(in tree like structure).

What I am getting is plain string