# Visualize ANTLR generated AST of a Java code in Python

Tags: python, parsing, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree, graphviz

I build Java Parser using ANTLR in python. Here Is the main code I used to parse JAVA code.

```
def ASTconversion(file_path):
    code = open(file_path, 'r').read()
    lexer = JavaLexer(antlr4.InputStream(code))
    stream = antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = JavaParser(stream)
    tree = parser.compilationUnit()
    is_syntax_errors = tree.parser._syntaxErrors #Binary
    return tree.toStringTree(recog=parser),is_syntax_errors

ast, is_syntax_errors = ASTconversion(code_path)
print(ast)
```

The following contains the output of the above code snippet.

> (compilationUnit (typeDeclaration (classOrInterfaceModifier public) (classDeclaration class Number (classBody { (classBodyDeclaration (block { (blockStatement (statement (expression (expression (expression (primary System)) . out) . (methodCall println ( (expressionList (expression (primary (literal "Printing Numbers")))) ))) ;)) (blockStatement (statement for ( (forControl (forInit (localVariableDeclaration (typeType (primitiveType int)) (variableDeclarators (variableDeclarator (variableDeclaratorId i) = (variableInitializer (expression (primary (literal (integerLiteral 1))))))))) ; (expression (expression (primary i)) <= (expression (primary (literal (integerLiteral 10))))) ; (expressionList (expression (expression (primary i)) ++))) ) (statement (block { (blockStatement (statement (expression (expression (expression (primary System)) . out) . (methodCall println ( (expressionList (expression (primary i))) ))) ;)) })))) })) }))) )

Based on this output I have 2 questions to ask.

```
     1. How I can visualize this parser output as a Graphical AST? 
     2. If the code contains any syntax error I can find that as in the code. But How can I track the syntax error?
```

Comment: There are a lot of tools for visualization of the CST. Have you tried the basic ["grun" tool](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md#a-first-example)? It does require Java, though.

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear that the Python target has the ability for you to produce the gun parse tree view from within your Python code.  This makes sense as that's a Java app in the Java runtime.

If you follow the [ANTLR Quick start](https://www.antlr.org), you should have the `grun` command installed, and (assuming you have no Python-specific semantic predicates, headers, etc. in your grammar), you would be able to use the `-gui` option with `grun` to see a graphical representation of your parse tree.

Also, both the Visual Studio Code, and IntelliJ ANTLR plugins, give you the ability to test input against a grammar and see a visualization of your parse tree in the IDE ([VS Code plugin](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4)) ([IntelliJ plugin](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4)).

In order to get your errors back from a parse, you should probably take a look at the [ctest.py](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Python3/tests/ctest.py) test for the Python runtime.  It will show you how to implement your own errorListener:

an excerpt:

```
class ErrorListener(antlr4.error.ErrorListener.ErrorListener):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ErrorListener, self).__init__()
        self.errored_out = False

    def syntaxError(self, recognizer, offendingSymbol, line, column, msg, e):
        self.errored_out = True


def sub():
    # Parse the input file
    input_stream = antlr4.FileStream("c.c")

    lexer = CLexer(input_stream)
    token_stream = antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer)

    parser = CParser(token_stream)


    errors = ErrorListener()
    parser.addErrorListener(errors)
```

Of course, you'd substitute your own code to gather and retain errors in your extension of the `ErrorListener` class.  The key take-away is that you need to implement your own error listener and then use `addErrorlistener()` to use it (you may also want to call `removeErrorListner()` to remove the default listener that probably just writes out to sysout).

Comment: Thank you for the answers, it's really helpful. But still couldn't able to visualize the AST. I have  followed the steps in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60617218/parsing-some-java-code-with-python-using-antlr) . I want more convenient method to Visualize the AST using the output I mentioned.