# How to parse Java code in Python using ANTLRv4

Tags: python, java, python-3.x, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to parse some Java code in Python using ANTLRv4. I've tried to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60617218/parsing-some-java-code-with-python-using-antlr), but I get the following error:

```sh
  File "/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/antlr/proto_antlr.py", line 14, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/antlr/proto_antlr.py", line 9, in main
    tree = parser.compilationUnit()
  File "/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/antlr/Java8Parser.py", line 4182, in compilationUnit
    self.enterRule(localctx, 62, self.RULE_compilationUnit)
  File "/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/lib/python3.8/site-packages/antlr4/Parser.py", line 374, in enterRule
    self._ctx.start = self._input.LT(1)
  File "/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/lib/python3.8/site-packages/antlr4/CommonTokenStream.py", line 62, in LT
    self.lazyInit()
  File "/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/lib/python3.8/site-packages/antlr4/BufferedTokenStream.py", line 187, in lazyInit
    self.setup()
  File "/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/lib/python3.8/site-packages/antlr4/BufferedTokenStream.py", line 190, in setup
    self.sync(0)
  File "/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/lib/python3.8/site-packages/antlr4/BufferedTokenStream.py", line 112, in sync
    fetched = self.fetch(n)
  File "/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/lib/python3.8/site-packages/antlr4/BufferedTokenStream.py", line 124, in fetch
    t = self.tokenSource.nextToken()
  File "/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/lib/python3.8/site-packages/antlr4/Lexer.py", line 130, in nextToken
    self._tokenStartLine = self._interp.line_number
AttributeError: 'LexerATNSimulator' object has no attribute 'line_number'
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The file I'm trying to parse is [proper Java](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin/blob/3118642fb47024830dcf1e29aea2f2e173bc6e9f/src/main/java/io/fabric8/maven/docker/AbstractDockerMojo.java), it's extracted from the [docker-maven-plugin](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin) package. I've tried with other files, but I get the same error.

Any idea ?

Comment: AttributeError: 'LexerATNSimulator' object has no attribute 'line_number'

Comment: Which version of antlr4 do you use to create the parser? Which version of the antlr4-python3-runtime do you use to run the generated parser?

Comment: How did you install the antlr4-python3-runtime? I couldn't find the string `line_number` in the antlr4-python3-runtime packages that I inspected (downloaded from pypi, versions 4.9.2 and 4.8)

Comment: Note that this is not a problem with the java code that you are trying to parse - this is a problem with the antlr4 runtime where one class of the antlr4 runtime (antlr4.Lexer) tries to access an attribute in another class of the antlr4 runtime (antlr4.atn.LexerATNSimulator) that doesn't exist.

Comment: @ThomasKläger I'm using antlr 4.9.2 and antlr4-python3-runtime 4.9.2 downloaded using `pip install`. If you have any working duo of versions, I can try it.

Comment: For me the version 4.9.2 works fine. Can you verify that in the file `/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/lib/python3.8/site-packages/antlr4/Lexer.py` the line 130 matches the original line as for example viewable at https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/4.9.2/runtime/Python3/src/antlr4/Lexer.py#L130 ? If the line doesn't match I would suggest that you remove the `/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/lib/python3.8/site-packages/antlr4` directory and reinstall the antlr4-python3-runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was just a problem of violent refactorization... I've changed line to line_number in my code, and it actually changed it in librairies too. Changing it back to `line` cleared the problem.

Thanks to @Thomas Kläger for making me realize it.